# Why is datestr('19-01-2004') = 26-Jun-0024 in MATLAB R2011a?

Tags: matlab

I also tried the following:

```
datestr('19-01-2004','dd-mm-yyyy')

ans =

26-06-0024
```

I am new to MATLAB, so I am not sure what else to check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the function `datestr()`, the 2nd parameter denotes how the *output* should look like. It doesn't say anything about the input.

Essentially, you try to perform 2 steps: parse a string and then format the parsed date again.

So you can do

```
n = datenum('19-01-2004','dd-mm-yyyy')
datestr(n, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

and you'll get an `n` of 731965 and a final output of `2004-01-19`.

You can as well do

```
v = datevec('19-01-2004','dd-mm-yyyy')
datestr(v, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

and your `v` becomes `[2004 1 19 0 0 0]`.

So remember: step 1 - parsing of input with the appropriate format string, step 2 - formatting of output with the wanted format string.

If you want to give the date in a "clean" and readable format, you could just do

```
v = [2004 1 19 0 0 0]
datestr(v, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
datestr(v, 'dd.mm.yyyy')
datestr(v, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Answer (score 4):

When using [`datestr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) to convert a date string from one form to another, the format of the input date string is limit to those [listed here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html#input_argument_datestringin).  The format of your input `'19-01-2004'` is `'dd-mm-yyyy'` and is not one of the supported formats.

If we change the input string to `'01/19/2004'`, which is the supported format `'mm/dd/yyyy'`, we get the correct output:

```
>> datestr('01/19/2004','dd-mm-yyyy')
ans =
19-01-2004
```

To circumvent the limited number of supported input formats, the [documentation recommends](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html#zmw57dd0e158656) using [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) first.  So you can map your original input onto itself like:

```
>> datestr(datenum('19-01-2004','dd-mm-yyyy'),'dd-mm-yyyy')
ans =
19-01-2004
```

---

As for why MATLAB returns the date it does has to do with how it handles the unknown format.
I suspect whatever method they use to finally decide upon a format results in a really small date number, hence the year 24 output.